# Can we have object as a function in OOJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have faced above question during my past interview.I said no..I have doubt in this..I dono that how really we could use object as a function?

Comment: You can't use every object as a function. But you can use every function as an object coz it is an object. Try `objName instanceof Function`, if it returns true than it can be used as a function.

Comment: Got it..Thanks @kloik friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can, because every `function` is also an `object` in JS. But not vice versa

I have a `function` and also have a `property` in it. So I can call it and use it's properties

```js
function hello(){
   console.log('Hello');
}

hello.someProp = 'Some Prop';

hello();
console.log(hello.someProp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to elaborate a little bit.

The reason why JavaScript is really Object Oriented is because whenever you declare a function, its is nothing but new instance of JavaScript's **built-in object** called **Function**.

For e.g. when you declare **var a = {},** **Object** constructor creates a new object. Similarly, whenever you declare some function like **function SomFucn(){} Function** constructor creates new function.

So yes, we can use function as an object because but not vice versa.

Checkout below code. Working fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/95ejaydL/ (check console);

```
console.log(typeof(Object));

console.log(typeof(Function));


Function.prototype.sayHello = "Hello function property";

Object.prototype.sayHello = "Hello Object";

var a = {};

console.log(a.sayHello);

function Hello(){
  console.log("Hello from method");
}

Hello();

console.log(Hello.sayHello);

a();
```

Let me know if this was useful.

Thanks.